# Garage Door Operation Inconsistent (But ONLY with the Universal Remote)

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have the problem that many others have had here *except* that my door has stopped working with the universal remote (roof of the GM car) ONLY.  The Lift-Master remotes work well.  Initially, it was just the Buick, but now the Chevy is having the same problem.  On occasion, it will open after 10+ tries.

I'm stumped both cars were able to open the unit when they were set-up.  About 6 months later the Buick quit; then the Chevy.  There are no CFL bulbs in close proximity.  Nothing has changed in the garage since we moved in the house 5 years ago. And nothing changed in either auto.

Any ideas?  My thanks to you all!

Comment: did you try reprogramming them? if they went out at different times, that sounds like two isolated failures. Often if the battery dies, the remote code gets lost. sometimes it gets lost anyway, just for fun.

Comment: What is the make and model of the universal remote?

Comment: The remotes are built internal to each auto. It will open with all the 'clickers' but not the overhead.